Export Clob using TPT
I've got very simple 1 column table, and that 1 column is defined as CLOB, with no specified length.  Far as I know, that means the max length is 2097088000.
I am trying to dump this out to a text file using TPT. I'm confident that each row will be less than 1MB, so I'm trying to do this with the inline method.  Here's the relevant bits of the script:
DEFINE JOB EXPORT_FILTER_FILE
(
    DEFINE SCHEMA FILE_SCHEMA
    (
        clob_col CLOB
    );

    DEFINE OPERATOR SQL_SELECT
    TYPE SELECTOR
    SCHEMA FILE_SCHEMA
    ATTRIBUTES
    (
        VARCHAR Tdpid = 'TDInstance',
        VARCHAR LogonMech = 'LDAP',
        ...
        VARCHAR SelectStmt = 'select clob_col from db.table;'
    );

    DEFINE OPERATOR FILE_WRITER
    ...

    APPLY TO OPERATOR (FILE_WRITER)
    SELECT * FROM OPERATOR (SQL_SELECT);
);

When I execute this script, I get the following error:
    TPT_INFRA: TPT02638: Error: Conflicting data length for column(1) - clob_col. 
Source column's data length (64000) Target column's data length (2097088000).

Why does it think the source column's length is 64k, when it's defined as a clob?

The default CLOB(2097088000) is too large for inline mode. Declare an explicit length like CLOB(1000000) in the SCHEMA.

If I try to give any specific length > 64k for the clob (clob_col CLOB(64001)), I get a series of errors like Invalid input column length, size = Length Error.   64k or less works fine, but that defeats the purpose.

Looks like the inline method may not be supported for retrieving data > 64000. You have to use DEFERRED BY NAME to retrieve larger data.

Using deferred works, thanks!  Not sure what the point of the inline method is, if it maxes out at 64k, but oh well.

Inline is fully implemented for loading data, but not for retrieval.
